# Eliminating shaky scrolling in Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, multiprocessing

How can I make the app scroll faster without shaking?

Have been facing a lot challenge trying to get the scroll bar of my app to be responsive. The fact there is that I think the scroll bar is doing a heavy job which python neglects naturally.

How can I link multiprocessing module to work with the scroll bar as a result of that is to make it more responsive.

The scroll bar job is scrolling bunch of text widgets like excel spreadsheet, scrolling 2 canvasses at the same time using `yview(*args)`  calling a function that binds the two canvasses.
Pls any one that can help

```
from tkinter import *
import ctypes
import threading
from tkinter import ttk
#this will only work on windows
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)
class Financial:
   def __init__(self,main):


       root.withdraw()
       self.top=Toplevel()

   def get(self):
      self.width=self.top.winfo_screenwidth()
      self.height=self.top.winfo_screenheight()


      self.v=IntVar()
      self.v.set(round(0.00625*self.width))
      #Main canvas that contains the spreadsheet widgets
      self.c = Canvas(self.top,borderwidth=0,width=self.width//1.7,
                     height=self.height//1.2705882353,bg='#EBEBE6',highlightthickness=0,highlightbackground='blue')
      #container frame for the main csnvas
      self.f2=Frame(self.c,bg='#EBEBE6')
      #canvas that contains the row names i.e cell row names
      self.c2=Canvas(self.top,bg='#EBEBE6',width=self.width//6.7605633803,
                   height=self.height//1.2705882353,borderwidth=0,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
      #frame that contains the cell row names i.e cell row names
      self.f3=Frame(self.c2,bg='#EBEBE6',)
      self.test10=Frame(self.top) 
      self.sc=Scrollbar(self.test10,orient='horizontal',command=self.scroll1)
      self.sc1=Scrollbar(self.top,orient='vertical',command=self.scroll)

      #The spreadsheet 
      for ip in range(50):
        for jp in range(1):
            
            g0= Text(self.f3, font=('blue',self.v.get()+1),bd=1,width=18,height=0,wrap=None,undo=True,cursor='arrow',highlightthickness=0,)
            g0.grid(row=ip, column=jp+2,sticky='nsew')
            
            #Grid.rowconfigure(self.f3,ip,weight=1)
            #Grid.columnconfigure(self.f3,jp+2,weight=1)
            #wep=ttk.Separator(self.f3,orient='vertical')
            #wep.grid(row=ip,column=jp+3,sticky='ns')
            list9.append(g0)
      for i in range(50):
        for j in range(1):
            g = Text(self.f2, font=('blue',self.v.get()+1),bd=1,width=18,height=0,
                   wrap=None,undo=True,cursor='plus',state='disabled')
            #g.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.focus4)
            #g.bind('<FocusIn>',self.focus)
            #g.bind('<KeyPress>',self.focus5)
            g.grid(row=i+1, column=j+1)
            Grid.rowconfigure(self.f2,i+1,weight=1)
            Grid.columnconfigure(self.f2,j+1,weight=1)
            wep=ttk.Separator(self.f2,orient='vertical',style='Line.TSeparator')
            wep.grid(row=i+1,column=j+1,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,sticky='ns')
            kist.append(g)
      for i2 in range(50):
           for j2 in range(1):
            g2 = Text(self.f2, font=('blue',self.v.get()+1),bd=1,width=18,height=0,
                   wrap=None,undo=True,cursor='plus',state='disabled')
            #g2.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.focus4)
            #g2.bind('<FocusIn>',self.focus)
            #g2.bind('<KeyPress>',self.focus5)
            g2.grid(row=i2+1, column=j2+3)
            Grid.rowconfigure(self.f2,i2+1,weight=1)
            Grid.columnconfigure(self.f2,j2+1,weight=1)
            wep=ttk.Separator(self.f2,orient='vertical',style='Line.TSeparator')
            wep.grid(row=i2+1,column=j2+3,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,sticky='ns')
      for i3 in range(50):
           for j3 in range(1):
            g3 = Text(self.f2, font=('blue',self.v.get()+1),bd=1,width=18,height=0,
                   wrap=None,undo=True,cursor='plus',state='disabled')
            #g3.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.focus4)
            #g3.bind('<FocusIn>',self.focus)
            #g3.bind('<KeyPress>',self.focus5)
            g3.grid(row=i3+1, column=j3+4)
            Grid.rowconfigure(self.f2,i3+1,weight=1)
            Grid.columnconfigure(self.f2,j3+1,weight=1)
            wep=ttk.Separator(self.f2,orient='vertical',style='Line.TSeparator')
            wep.grid(row=i3+1,column=j3+4,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,sticky='ns')
      for i4 in range(50):
           for j4 in range(1):
            g4 = Text(self.f2, font=('blue',self.v.get()+1),bd=1,width=18,height=0,
                   wrap=None,undo=True,cursor='plus',state='disabled')
            #g4.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.focus4)
            #g4.bind('<FocusIn>',self.focus)
            #g4.bind('<KeyPress>',self.focus5)
            g4.grid(row=i4+1, column=j4+5)
            Grid.rowconfigure(self.f2,i4+1,weight=1)
            Grid.columnconfigure(self.f2,j4+1,weight=1)
            wep=ttk.Separator(self.f2,orient='vertical',style='Line.TSeparator')
            wep.grid(row=i4+1,column=j4+5,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,sticky='ns')
      for i5 in range(50):
         for j5 in range(1):
            g5 = Text(self.f2, font=('blue',self.v.get()+1),bd=1,width=18,height=0,
                   wrap=None,undo=True,cursor='plus',state='disabled')
            #g.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.focus4)
            #g.bind('<FocusIn>',self.focus)
            #g.bind('<KeyPress>',self.focus5)
            g5.grid(row=i5+1, column=j5+6)
            Grid.rowconfigure(self.f2,i+1,weight=1)
            Grid.columnconfigure(self.f2,j+1,weight=1)
            wep=ttk.Separator(self.f2,orient='vertical',style='Line.TSeparator')
            wep.grid(row=i5+1,column=j5+6,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,sticky='ns')
            
       for i6 in range(50):
          for j6 in range(1):
            g6 = Text(self.f2, font=('blue',self.v.get()+1),bd=1,width=18,height=0,
                   wrap=None,undo=True,cursor='plus',state='disabled')
            #g.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.focus4)
            #g.bind('<FocusIn>',self.focus)
            #g.bind('<KeyPress>',self.focus5)
            g6.grid(row=i6+1, column=j6+7)
            Grid.rowconfigure(self.f2,i+1,weight=1)
            Grid.columnconfigure(self.f2,j+1,weight=1)
            wep=ttk.Separator(self.f2,orient='vertical',style='Line.TSeparator')
            wep.grid(row=i6+1,column=j6+7,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,sticky='ns')
            
      
      
            
      
            
      
            
      
      self.c.update_idletasks()
      self.c2.update_idletasks()
      self.c.grid(row=4,column=3,sticky='nsew')
      self.c.create_window(0,0,anchor='w',window=self.f2)
      self.c2.create_window(0,0,anchor='w',window=self.f3)
      self.c2.config(scrollregion=self.c2.bbox('all'),yscrollcommand=self.sc1.set)
      self.c2.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky='nsew')
      self.c2.yview_moveto(0.0)
      self.c2.xview_moveto(0.0)
      self.c.configure(scrollregion=self.c.bbox('all'),yscrollcommand=self. sc1.set,xscrollcommand=self.sc.set)
      self.c.yview_moveto(0.0)
      self.c.xview_moveto(0.0)
      self.sc.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
      self.sc1.grid(row=4,column=4,sticky='nsew')

   def scroll(self,*args):
      threading.Thread(target=self.c.yview(*args)).start()
      threading.Thread(target=self.c2.yview(*args)).start()
   def scroll1(self,*args):
      threading.Thread(target=self.c.xview(*args)).start()
      
      #threading.Thread(target=self.top.update).start()
kist=[]
list9=[]
if __name__=='__main__':
  root=Tk()
  master=Financial(root)
  master.get()
  root.mainloop()
```

it works well on linux but on windows it lags.

Comment: muliprocessing will almost certainly make it slower, not faster.

Comment: You aren't using threading properly. `target=self.c.yview(*args)` will immediately call `self.c.yview(*args)` and then set `target` to `None`.

Comment: How can I leverage the threading module well